# iOS UITableView reloadData show empty screen

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am loading data from server in iOS and then add them to table data source, the problem that sometimes the screen is empty until I touch or the scroll the screen and then every thing is appear, can any one tell me what is the problem and how can I slove it ?

Comment: Hope you are not accessing UIViews from non-main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After loading data from your server , always reload on the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Post some code if you need further help.

Comment: Ok will try it and get back to you if I face any problem, Thanks